# "I understood her to say"

Tags: grammaticality, conversation

> ‘I did. But when I reached the telephone, he had grown tired of waiting and had rung off. I should never have allowed Miss Wickham to take me away from the house.’
>   ‘She wanted you to see the big fish.’
>   ‘So I understood her to say.’

Can anyone help me with construction of the last sentence. Is it common in English?
I was expecting 'So I understood what she said.'

Comment: If this is all from the same speaker, 'Or so I understood her to say.' would be more expected.

Comment: It is from two speakers. Actually, I was expecting: 'So I understood her saying'.

Comment: The key to this is confusion over how 'so' is used.

Comment: I can't really comment on whether it is *strictly* correct, but it's not terrible English, at the least. Sometimes you might hear English speakers say, 'I understood it to mean...' This sentence is similar.

Answer (score 2):

["Oxford Dictionary"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/understand/) gives a hint about this particular usage of the verb 'understand'.

**understand somebody/something to be/have something:** [transitive] (formal) to think or believe that something is true because you have been told that it is

Eg: The Prime Minister is understood to have been extremely angry about the report.

In the above question, this was exactly the context there. 'So I understood her to say' ==  'I understood her to say so' == 'She is understood (by me) to say so'

P.S. : The author is PG Wodehouse, a Brit, who sometimes uses these formal phrases in his writings.

Answer (score 2):

> So I understood her to say.

"So" here means roughly "that".

It's easier to grasp in the phrase "if you say so".  "So" is effectively a pronoun: if you say [whatever you just said], I will believe you.

In the example, the "so" is Miss Wickham wants you to see the big fish (jeez, what kind of story is this?)

When the speaker says "So I understood her to say", he means, "I hold the opinion that Miss Wickham said she wants me to see the big fish."

"Understood" is being used in a way that is somewhat dated now (or perhaps just somewhat British): he does not mean that it was particularly difficult to learn, only that he believes it to be the case but is deferentially allowing that other people might disagree or that he might be mistaken.

"What are you doing here?"

"I understood [i.e., it was my belief] that this was a public place."

In the US, I have mostly heard it sarcastically; the speaker is underlining that the belief is obviously true or common knowledge by pretending it might not be.